# Why can't I compile structured bindings?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, clang++

I was trying to compile this code (in the file test.cpp)

```
#include<tuple>

int main(){
  auto [c,d] = make_tuple(3.1,2.3);
}
```

using 
     `g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test`
, as well as 
     `clang++ -std=c++1z test.cpp -o test`
both would print the error message:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:3:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
auto [c,d] = make_tuple(3.1,2.3);
```

using 
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
and 
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4
(using Ubuntu 16.04.09)
What am I missing?

Comment: Use a newer version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the official website of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html):

- Structured bindings  is supported in gcc version 7

From the official website of [clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html):

- Structured bindings  is supported in version 4.

The following link presents compiler support for new C++ features.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support